# Use Anaconda python instead of default mac python

Tags: python, path, anaconda

I want to use Anaconda python instead of the one installed by default on MacOS. When I use:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

However, my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` have the following line:

```
export PATH=~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH
```

How do set Anaconda python as default?

Answer (score 3):

My Anaconda3 installation already set that in my `.bash_profile` (indicated by comment). Try using the absolute path (and replacing `{username}` with your actual username) and adding quotes like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/{username}/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```